# Matching multiple occurrence of the same character with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

how can i find multiple occurrence of the same character?
something like:

```
$maxRepeat = 3;

"pool" passes

"poool" don't
```

i need this to work for any character, so i guess I'll have to escape special characters like . and \

which characters i have to escape?

do you know any good reference to `preg_match` regexp apart from the one on php.net?

Answer (score 4):

You use [quantifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) for this

```
preg_match("/p(o){1,3}ls/",$string);
```

*Excerpt:*

```
The following standard quantifiers are recognized:

1. * Match 0 or more times
2. + Match 1 or more times
3. ? Match 1 or 0 times
4. {n} Match exactly n times
5. {n,} Match at least n times
6. {n,m} Match at least n but not more than m times
```

My favorite resource for learning **P**erl **Reg**ular Expressions is the time honored [camel book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271). But if you don't have one handy, [this site](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) is pretty good.

Comment: I think he wants the regex to work for any string, not just pool and not just the letter o repeating - like `$string = 'aaaaany word';`

Answer (score 1):

found, what i need is

if(preg_match('/(.)\1/', $t)) return true;

this returns true for $t = 'aa'; // any char

if(preg_match('/(.)\1\1/', $t)) return true;

this returns true for $t = 'aaa'; // any char

and so on

Answer (score -1):

```
/.{1,2}/         # 2 is limit, 1 to have at least one character
```

any character repeated up to so many times, you'll have to format your regex if your `$amxRepeate` is an int.

Comment: dot will match any character, not the same character repeating. So "oo" will match but "ao" will also match