# Remove Array value

Tags: php, arrays

```
[0] => LR-153-TKW
[1] => Klaten
[2] => Rectangular
[3] => 12x135x97
```

I have an array looking like this. and I want to completely remove  12x135x97 to the mother array so how would i do this?

Comment: is this entry always exists at the end of your array?

Comment: With [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)? Finding the answer to this question on Google would have been way less effort than posting it here. Seriously did you even look?

Comment: What's the mother array?

Comment: if you don't know the array index http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883421/removing-array-item-by-value

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unset($arr[3]);`. It will delete that array index. Whenever you want to delete an array value, you can use [PHP unset() method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

As you were asked into your comment:
`basically i just want to remove all index that have "X**X" this pattern digit 'x' digit`

Here is the code that you can use:

```
    $arr = array("LR-153-TKW", "Klaten", "Rectangular", "12x135x97", "xxxx");
    $pattern_matched_array = preg_grep("/^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]*/", $arr);
    if(count($pattern_matched_array) > 0)
    {
        foreach($pattern_matched_array as $key => $value)
        {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: basically i just want to remove all index that have "**X**X**" this pattern  digit 'x' digit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637941/matching-multiple-occurrence-of-the-same-character-with-preg-match

Comment: @ArunJain I guess you haven't seen the `PREG_GREP_INVERT` flag.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has unset() function. You can use it for deleting a variable or index of array.

```
unset($your_var[3]);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

Use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), to find it you can do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if($i == "12x135x97"){
        unset($array[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Unless you know the key, in which case you can do:

```
unset($array[3]);
```

its not the most time efficient if you array is thousands of items long, but for this job it will suffice.

To turn it into a method, would make for better coding.

```
function removeItem($item){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if($i == $item){
            unset($array[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

and call it like:

```
removeItem("12x135x97");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:
if you know the array key then you can do this

```
unset($arrayName[3]);
```

or if it's always at the end of your array

```
array_pop($arrayName);
```

this will remove the last value out of your array